Wrong tm_scale_bar when plotting osm raster (tmaptools)
I can't manage to plot osm-tiles created with tmaptools::read_osm with the correct scalebar, without distorting the osm-raster-layer.
library( tidyverse)
library( tmap)
library( tmaptools)
library( sf)


## start point (lon/lat)
coords <- matrix(c(9.10343, 
47.13597), 
ncol = 2)

## project coords 
start_p <- st_sfc(st_point(coords), 
crs = 4326) %>% 
st_transform( crs = 2056)

## buffer of 15km around point
buffer_p <- st_buffer( start_p, dist = 15000)


## load osm background layer (esri topo)
esri_map <- read_osm( bb( st_bbox(buffer_p), 
ext = 1.2),  
type = "esri-topo",
zoom = 11)

## Plot with wrong scalebar, but original background raster
## plot buffer of 15km with scalebar of 15km, should have the same length as the lake on the map... but is to short
tm_shape( esri_map)+
    tm_rgb()+
    tm_shape(buffer_p)+
    tm_borders()+
    tm_scale_bar( breaks = c(0,15))


## Plot with correct scalebar, but distorted raster layer
tm_shape( esri_map)+
tm_rgb()+
tm_shape(buffer_p,
is.master = T)+
tm_borders()+
tm_scale_bar( breaks = c(0,15))

I tried to transform the buffer_p to the same crs as the osm-layer with st_transform but faced the same problem. I think I lack the fundamental understanding on how tm_scale_bar() is working with projected rasters...
Any advice is highly appreciated.
